# Django crispy forms language settings

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

I am a beginner at web application development using django framework.
I am creating a crispy form to update the user information and upload an image.
The html file contains two forms, one for updating the information and second for uploading the image.

While the rest of the form language setting is us-en, only the button and text next to the upload button are seen in german language.

The settings.py file has the chosen language code as 'en-us'.

[image: settings.py file]

In the model.py file the forms are defined like below:
[image: form classes in model.py]

The forms are then used in the html file:
[image: use of the defined forms in the html file]

But the webpage shows the following:
[image]

could anyone please help me understand, what is making only the upload button language change to german and how could I possibly fix it?
Thank you :)

already tried: checking the language code in the settings.py file

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the file chooser language is determined by the browser language settings and not the language given in the settings.py file of the django project. This is because the file chooser is provided by the browser and not native to the crispy form.

FYI: Instead of deleting the post, I am answering my own question as the answer might help someone else who is facing a similar issue :)